# Unable to Add/Modify Mobile Phone field using IPP against QuickBooks desktop

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I can't seem to modify or add the Mobile phone field in QuickBooks for QB Desktop.  Online works fine, no dice in desktop but according to the XML response of the MOD request it seems to be working fine.

It shows the field being created/modified (idDomain is created, id value generated) however SyncManager never pushes the changes to QuickBooks.

I can modify the Mobile value on the QB side and I'll be able to see that change in my IPP application but no go when heading the other direction.

Here's the XML traces:

http://pastebin.com/qprwAh9z

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate this. The mobile phone number does not sync to the QB desktop file.Seems like a bug.
Please submit a support ticket here:
Link - http://developer.intuit.com/Support/Incident

Comment: Submitted.  I was seeing similar behavior with the Notes field and so submitted a ticket for that as well.

Comment: The notes field is not supported for read/write operations from API explorer/code. 
It is known case and we will update the docs for this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, the problem is when you use 'Mobile' in the Phone's 'Tag' field.

Instead of 'Mobile', I tried 'Home' in the Tag field. As an alternate solution you can try the following (I will take a look if there is any constraint in the intermediate QBXML/QBSDK side )

**IDS Req**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Add xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" RequestId="22f39648c5ab1111988854e808163dc9" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
        <ExternalRealmId>657117515</ExternalRealmId>
        <Object xsi:type="Customer">
        <TypeOf>Person</TypeOf>
        <Name>SampleCust-IDS12</Name>
        <Address>
    ...
        </Address>
        <Address>
    ...
        </Address>
        <Phone>
            <DeviceType>LandLine</DeviceType>
            <FreeFormNumber>0123456789</FreeFormNumber>
            <Default>1</Default>
            <Tag>Business</Tag>
        </Phone>
        <Phone>
            <DeviceType>LandLine</DeviceType>
            <FreeFormNumber>1234567890</FreeFormNumber>
            <Default>0</Default>
            <Tag>Home</Tag>
        </Phone>
    ...
        </Object>
    </Add>
```

**Create Response**

```
<RestResponse xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
  <Success RequestId="22f39648c5ab1111988854e808163dc9">
    <PartyRoleRef>
      <Id idDomain="NG">1221097</Id>
      <SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
      <LastUpdatedTime>2013-07-19T11:25:43Z</LastUpdatedTime>
      <PartyReferenceId idDomain="NG">1261065</PartyReferenceId>
    </PartyRoleRef>
    <RequestName>CustomerAdd</RequestName>
    <ProcessedTime>2013-07-19T11:25:43Z</ProcessedTime>
  </Success>
</RestResponse>
```

**QBXML** [ 2nd phone no is coming under **AltPhone** tag ]

```
<?qbxml version="9.0" ?>
<QBXML>
   <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError" newMessageSetID="13ff6ae6e2c76b59e49">
    <CustomerAddRq requestID="EsbKeyMapHeader:1221097:0">
        <CustomerAdd>
            <Name>SampleCust-IDS12</Name>
..
            <BillAddress>
...
            </BillAddress>
            <ShipAddress>
...
            </ShipAddress>
            <PrintAs>SampleCust</PrintAs>
            <Phone>0123456789</Phone>
            <AltPhone>1234567890</AltPhone>
            <Fax></Fax>
..
    </CustomerAddRq>
   </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

QB's view [ There is no specific field for Mobile. Mobile/LandLine is kindOf Metadata. I'll check and confirm this behaviour ]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I'm working with QB 2013 where there is a Mobile field.  Not sure how that impacts things.  If you populate the Mobile field on the QB side and query for that customer, Mobile is the value for the TAG and DEVICE TYPE fields so I naturally assumed to ensure the same going in the opposite direction.

Comment: And yes, as you've noted above, the Home/Landline Tag/DeviceType combination is how you (and I currently) map to the Alt Phone field.  Not sure how this helps with the Mobile problem.

Comment: Right now, As I don't hv QB'13 in my system, so I can't test this behavior. I'll try to confirm this on Monday.( I agree that, the behavior is not so intuitive)

- Customer notes cannot be synced to QBD. Confirmed.  I'll  raise a doc change request for this.